# How to use Fredholm alternative to check that there are only finite eigenvalues of $H$ on the imaginary axis?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, schrodinger-operators

On $\mathbb{R}^3$, we consider the operator
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}= \left(  \begin{matrix}
    -\Delta +1 -2 \phi^2 & -\phi^2 \\
    \phi^2 & \Delta -1 +2 \phi^2
\end{matrix} \right) , D(\mathcal{H})=H^2 \times H^2 (\mathbb{R}^3)\subset L^2 \times L^2(\mathbb{R}^3),
\label{linearized oeprator: general case}
\end{equation}
where $\phi$ is the ground state of $-\Delta u  + u= u^3$, and $\phi$ is strictly positive, radial, decreasing, smooth, and exponentially-decaying. Moreover, we can see that $\sigma_{ess}(\mathcal{H})= (-\infty, 1] \cup [1, \infty)$. Thus we are curious about the properties of discrete spectum of $\mathcal H$, expecially on the imaginary axis, which is eaiser to talk about than what on $[-1,1] \setminus \{ 0 \}$. As for question above, in [W. Schlag: Stable manifolds for an orbitally unstable NLS](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405435), Schlag claimed in Proposition 16 that there are only finite eigenvalues of $\mathcal H$ on the imaginary axis. More precisely, there are only finite $\sigma \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} $ such that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal H f= i \sigma f, \quad f\in D(\mathcal {H})=H^2 \times H^2  \subset L^2 \times L^2.
\end{equation}

and he just said that it followed from Fredholm's alternative immediately, but I do not know how to check it. So can someone give me some tips about it?